# Key stretching algorithms vs throttling for password "hashing"

Tags: security, hash, password-protection

Why do people suggest using key stretching algorithms like bcrypt/pbkdf2 which take longer to calculate (on purpose), rather than using faster algorithms, which are also secure, like salted sha-256 or sha-512 and using a throttling mechanism to limit brute-force attacks?

Throttling is not CPU bound, and will deliver the same "delay" for brute-force attacks while still being fast for the average user. bcrypt/pbkdf2 on the other hand is CPU bound and will always be slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use key-stretching, then you prepare for the case that an attacker has stolen the hashes from your database. The attacker can then start an *offline attack* and brute-force with the full speed of his GPU/CPU to crack the passwords.

Only the absolute necessary code to calculate the hash is important then, since all other code like throttling can simply be left out. To set a minimum time per hash, you have to make the problem itself difficult to solve. That's key-stretching, there is no cheaper way as to calculate all the rounds of hashing, to get a comparable hash.

Some algorithms like BCrypt/SCrypt are additionally designed in a way, so that they are difficult to solve with a GPU.

Comment: That makes sense. But if an attacker were able to gain access to the hashes, that is a more pressing point in terms of security. In most cases the attacker would then also have gained access to private data of users. If one can assume the hashes (the database layer) are secure (which should be a design requirement, and administrative imperative), wouldn't the faster hashes then be the ideal solution still?

Comment: @Climax - In an ideal world where nobody is interested in your hashes, you could even store them plaintext. In the real world though, there are so many ways your hashes can leak, that you absolutely should use key-stretching (SQL-injection, thrown away backups, harddisks of discarded servers, hoster or db-admin). Keep in mind that people often reuse their passwords, so even if your site is unimportant, you could compromise more important site. Maybe you could be interested in my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) about securely storing passwords.

Comment: thanks your tutorial is excellent. I agree with your answer as it describes the scenario where bcrypt/scrypt is essential. I would like to ask, however, if one can use a sort of ephemeral hashmap cache to at least improve performance? The use case might be for API queries, where bcrypt would have to be executed in short succession for the same password.

Comment: @Climax - Ok, you have the problem of a rest server which has to authenticate for every request? This is normally solved with an authentication service, there you can do the authentication once and get a token. Like a session, this token has a certain lifetime and can be sent along with subsequent requests for authentication. Since this token is strong (in contrast to weak passwords), there is no need to use key-stretching or salting, just store a SHA-512 of this strong token in the database.

Comment: indeed, but also for a high volume site where there are hundreds or even thousands of authentication requests per second. For SHA this will be of no consequence. For bcrypt this will be a show stopper. In your example, the authentication service would also have to store the password somewhere, and for security that should be bcrypt. side-note: I use JWT for session management

Comment: @Climax - That's right, it is a trade-off between security and performance. Actually this is where the cost factor comes in, it is still better to use BCrypt with a small cost factor (maybe 1ms), than using a fast algorithm like SHA-1 where you can calculate [3Giga hashes/second](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance).